# How do I create a dashed line markup in the forge viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

Is there a way to set the style of a polyline markup to show as a dashed line in the Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore extension of the forge viewer?

I tried to use `markup.setStyle({ 'stroke-dasharray': "5,5" })` but that throws an undefined error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the built-in markups but you can definitely use a dashed line when defining your custom markup type. If you follow this [tutorial](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/implementing-custom-markups), and the [sample code](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-basic-app/tree/sample/custom-markup) that it links to, you can add the following line to your custom markup's `updateStyle` method:

```js
avemcu.setAttributeToMarkupSvg(shape, 'stroke-dasharray', '5,5');
```

And you get something like this:

[image]